# Update a flask webpage with socket.io

Tags: html, flask, socket.io

I am trying to update a flask page dynamically. My problem is that I cannot figure out how can I do that use `socketio.emit`.

My original code is this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import time


app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/SkapisBot/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.form['text']
        results = [text, text + "23424432"]
        response = {'results': results}

        # <Emit an event before sleeping>

        # Sleep for 5 seconds
        time.sleep(5)

        results.append(text + text)
        # <Emit an event>

        # Return a response
        return jsonify(response)
    return render_template('testing.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run(host ='0.0.0.0')
    socketio.run(app)
```

and my html file is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<head>
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <form id="myForm" method="POST">
        <i class="fa fa-search icon"></i>
        <input id="textInput" name="text" type="text" placeholder="Type a question here" style="font-style: italic; color: grey;" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <div id="resultContainer">
        <!-- Results will be displayed here -->
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myForm").on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ($("#textInput").val() === "") {
                    alert("Please enter a value for 'textInput'.");
                    return;
                }
                var question = $("#textInput").val();

                // Send an AJAX request to the server
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/SkapisBot/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { text: question},
                    success: function(response) {
                        // Update the result container with the received results
                        var results = response.results;

                        var resultContainer = $("#resultContainer");
                        resultContainer.empty();
                        
                        $.each(results, function(index, result) {
                            resultContainer.append('<h3>Result ' + (index + 1) + ':</h3><p>' + result + '</p>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

So what did I try to do? I tried to use the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927065/how-to-update-the-html-page-with-some-updates-while-flask-is-performing-a-task-v) but I am failing to understand how to adopt it to my case. I am not that good in both front-end and back-end.

Then I tried this:

```
@app.route('/SkapisBot/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def my_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.form['text']
        print(text)
        results =[text , text+"23424432"]
        # Return the initial response immediately
        response = {'results': results}
        socketio.emit('update_results', response, namespace='/SkapisBot/')
        time.sleep(5) 
        results.append(text+text)
        response = {'results': results}
        socketio.emit('update_results', response, namespace='/SkapisBot/')
        return jsonify({'message': 'Processing request'})
    return render_template('testing.html')
```

and my html script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:5000');

        socket.on('connect', function() {
            console.log('Connected to Socket.IO');
        });

        $("#myForm").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($("#textInput").val() === "") {
                alert("Please enter a value for 'textInput'.");
                return;
            }
            var question = $("#textInput").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/SkapisBot/",
                type: "POST",
                data: { text: question},
                
            });
        });

        // Listen for 'update_results' events and update the result container
        socket.on('update_results', function(data) {
            var results = data.results;

            var resultContainer = $("#resultContainer");
            resultContainer.empty();

            $.each(results, function(index, result) {
                resultContainer.append('<h3>Result ' + (index + 1) + ':</h3><p>' + result + '</p>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I am getting back `500`

What am I doing wrong?